# JQueryMobile: Load pages with Flip toggle switch

Tags: jquery-mobile-flipswitch, jquery-mobile-pageshow

I have jquery mobile html file with two pages.

`<div data-role="page" id="page1"></div>
 </div><div data-role="page" id="page2"></div>`

I want to use the jquery mobile flip toggle switch to load either of the pages,

`<select name="flip-1" id="flip-1" data-role="slider">
    <option value="off">Off</option>
    <option value="on">On</option>
</select>`

cant seem to get the function to function?

(I'm very newer to the functions behind jquery mobile/javascript)

I modeled after: http://jsfiddle.net/V7xeD/ to no success